# Azure AD: Does the app registration process takes time to register self-signed certificate?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, access-token, self-signed-certificate, azure-service-principal

1. I am creating an application in Azure tenant with Microsoft graph API. At the same time, I am also uploading a self-signed certificate for an application.
2. The OAuth client can request an access token by providing the user assertion. User assertion is self-signed x509 certificate.

I am observing different behaviors when trying to get access token using user assertion:

1. When tried to get access token for an application after 24 hrs of registration process, I am able to successfully get the access token.
2. When tried to get access token for an immediately registered application, it fails with following "Invalid_client" error.
   [image]

So, does the app registration process takes time to register self-signed certificate?

Comment: It should take some time to take effect, but I don't think it will take 24 hours, did you try it after about 30 mins?

Answer (score 0):

It should take some time to take effect, I can reproduce your issue with a new uploaded self-assigned certificate, it will not take 24 hours, after about 10-20 mins, it works fine.

Comment: Hi Joy, I tried after 1 hr. It was not working. It is taking longer time in my case to take effect.

Comment: @Pooja_2304 Well, the time depends on the specific tenant, it is also normal, don't worry about it.

Comment: ok. Newly created client secret for an application also shows similar behavior. Is that also expected behavior?

Comment: @Pooja_2304 Yes, did some test and add in your new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65665269/azure-ad-application-takes-time-to-activate/65676948#65676948